# Leaflet not styling the layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to style the layers i get from a server, but the layer.setStyle() function doesn't do anything and defining the style when creating the layer don't work either, i have my code like this:

```
var stateStyle = {
    "color": "#3D5229",
    "weight": 1,
    "opacity": .90,
    "fillOpacity": .90
}; 

  var mywms2 = L.tileLayer.wms("http://someserver/geoserver/somepage/wms", {
    layers: 'SomeMaps:view_table_geom',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
     style:  stateStyle , //not working
    version: '1.1.0'

});

//not working either

mywms2.setStyle(stateStyle);
```

What is the problem? this it shouldn't be an issue.

I made i plunker but for some reason it's not showing the map, but if you copy paste the code to a html code you can see what's my issue.
https://plnkr.co/edit/38VVojm8zLKhdXu10nQC?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet's `L.Tilelayer.WMS` options object doesn't have a `style` option. It does however support a `styles` option but it doesn't take a javascript object literal as a value but a string of comma-separated values:

> Comma-separated list of WMS styles.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms-styles

A good explanation on Leaflet and WMS styling can be found here in the answer by Per Liedman:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23012106/2019281

Comment: like this `styles:  stateStyle ,` ? now the layer is not shown =/

Comment: If you read my answer, it clearly states that it takes a string of comma-separated values NOT a javascript object literal as you have in your example. I even linked to the reference. Plus the style properties you are using may not be supported by the WMS server you are using. That's all explained in the answer i've linked to.